# hide the last 3 columns and see them only when we click on the + Datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I can't hide the last 3 columns I just want to see them when I hit the + sign

```
        $('#articulos_elevalunas').DataTable({
           "order": [1,'asc'],   
           "info": true,        
           "responsive": {  details: true},
           "initComplete": function( settings, json ) {
                mosrarDataGrid();
            },
            'columnDefs' : [

                {
                    className: 'control',
                    orderable: false,
                    targets: -1
                }


            ],
           "language": {
               "url": rutaJsonIdioma
           }

        });

        }
```

**[[enter image description here][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJXzO.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eTKGU.png)**

I want something like this:
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/auto.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are searching for [`control classes`](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/column-control/classes.html)

- `all` - Always display
- `none` - Don't display as a column, but show in the child row
- `never` - Never display
- `control` - Used for the column responsive.details.type option.

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
  responsive: {
    details: {
      type: 'column'
    }
  },
  columnDefs: [{
    className: 'control',
    orderable: false,
    targets: 0
  }],
  order: [1, 'asc']
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.3/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display nowrap" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th class="all">First name</th>
      <th class="all">Last name</th>
      <th class="all">Position</th>
      <th class="all">Office</th>
      <th class="all">Age</th>
      <th class="none">Start date</th>
      <th class="none">Salary</th>
      <th class="none">Extn.</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Tiger</td>
      <td>Nixon</td>
      <td>System Architect</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2011/04/25</td>
      <td>$320,800</td>
      <td>5421</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Garrett</td>
      <td>Winters</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>63</td>
      <td>2011/07/25</td>
      <td>$170,750</td>
      <td>8422</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Ashton</td>
      <td>Cox</td>
      <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td>San Francisco</td>
      <td>66</td>
      <td>2009/01/12</td>
      <td>$86,000</td>
      <td>1562</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Cedric</td>
      <td>Kelly</td>
      <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td>Edinburgh</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>2012/03/29</td>
      <td>$433,060</td>
      <td>6224</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Airi</td>
      <td>Satou</td>
      <td>Accountant</td>
      <td>Tokyo</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>2008/11/28</td>
      <td>$162,700</td>
      <td>5407</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td>Brielle</td>
      <td>Williamson</td>
      <td>Integration Specialist</td>
      <td>New York</td>
      <td>61</td>
      <td>2012/12/02</td>
      <td>$372,000</td>
      <td>4804</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I want something like this:https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/auto.html

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can hide the single column using

```
var table = $('#articulos_elevalunas').DataTable();
table.column( 0 ).visible( false );
```

Also if you want to hide the multiple columns then you can use the following code

```
var table = $('#articulos_elevalunas').DataTable();

for ( var i=7 ; i<10 ; i++ ) {
   table.column( i ).visible( false, false );
}
table.columns.adjust().draw( false );  // adjust column sizing and redraw
```

and after that on click of +sign you can add the true to make it visible.

Let me know if this will work for you else I will put this on code-pen.

Comment: I don't want it to be totally hidden, but I only want to see those 3 columns when I click on +

Comment: I want something like this: https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/auto.html